# What is the latus rectum of a hyperbola with eccentricity $= 2$, one focus being $(2,4)$, and one asymptote being $2x-y=5$?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> One of the asymptotes of hyperbola is $2x-y =5$ and one focus is $(2,4)$. It's eccentricity is 2. Find its latus rectum.

My attempt

 We know that the angle between an asymptote and the line joining focus and centre is $$\arccos \frac1e =\arccos \frac12 = \frac\pi3 $$.
 To rotate the given asymptote by an angle of $\frac\pi3$, I replaced $x$ and $y$ with $x'$and $y'$ where $$\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y' \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac12 & -\frac{\sqrt3}{2} \\ \frac{\sqrt3}{2} & \frac12 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y \end{bmatrix}$$ which yields $$\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y' \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac x2 -\frac{\sqrt3}{2}y\\\frac{\sqrt3}{2}x+\frac y2 \end{bmatrix}$$
Substituting this into the equation for asymptote, we get the rotated line as:
$$x(1-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}) -y(\sqrt3 + \frac12) + k =0$$
This line should pass through the given focus $(2,4)$, substituting these coordinates we obtain $k=5\sqrt3$, so the equation of line joining focus and centre is $$x(1-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}) -y(\sqrt3 + \frac12) + 5\sqrt3=0$$
I got stuck here, and don't really know how to proceed. Can somebody help solve it further?
PS: I'm still in highschool, so it would be appreciated if you do not use highly advanced concepts to solve this.
Thank you.

Comment: As you said, you know the angle $\theta$ between the asymptote and the major axis. Draw a small diagram of the situation, to determine where the center of the hyperbola could be.  You will see that if $d$ is the distance between the given focus $f$ and the given asymptote, then $fC = d / sin \theta $.  But $fC = a e - a $, hence you can find $a$.  And this leads to $b$, and consequently to the latus rectum which is equal to $\dfrac{2 b^2}{a} $

Comment: @HosamH If we have a standard hyperbola, $C$ is $(0,0)$ and $f$ is $(ae,0)$, so $fC$ should be $ae$ not $ae-a$, no?

Comment: Yes.  You're absolutely right, sorry about the mistake.

Comment: Using the focus/directrix/eccentricity equation $$(a^2+b^2)((x-2)^2+(y-4)^2)-2^2(ax+by-c)^2=0$$ for focus $(2,4),$ directrix $ax+by=c,$ and eccentricity 2; or $$(-3a^2+b^2)x^2-8abxy+(a^2-3b^2)y^2+(-4a^2-4b^2+8ac)x+(-8a^2-8b^2+8bc)y+20a^2+20b^2-4c^2=0$$ we find it has has asymptotes $$(-3a^2+b^2)x^2-8abxy+(a^2-3b^2)y^2+(-4a^2-4b^2+8ac)x+(-8a^2-8b^2+8bc)y-(16c^2+((-32b)-16a)c+4b^2+64ab-44a^2)/3=0$$ and we demand that this has a factor $2x-y-5.$

Comment: Knowing that the factorization is $$(b^2-3a^2)\cdot\\((x-\frac{4ac+6b^2-16ab-2a^2}{3b^2+3a^2})-((\sqrt3b^2+4ab+\sqrt3a^2)/(b^2-3a^2))(y-\frac{4bc-4b^2-8ab+12a^2}{3b^2+3a^2}))\cdot\\((x-\frac{4ac+6b^2-16ab-2a^2}{3b^2+3a^2})+((\sqrt3b^2-4ab+\sqrt3a^2)/(b^2-3a^2)))(y-\frac{4bc-4b^2-8ab+12a^2}{3b^2+3a^2})$$ we get $$\begin{align}((\sqrt3b^2+4ab+\sqrt3a^2)/(b^2-3a^2))&=\frac12\\((-\frac{4ac+6b^2-16ab-2a^2}{3b^2+3a^2})-((\sqrt3b^2+4ab+\sqrt3a^2)/(b^2-3a^2))(-\frac{4bc-4b^2-8ab+12a^2}{3b^2+3a^2}))=-\frac52\end{align}$$

which one can solve to get e.g. $a=-1.839230484541327,b=2.785640646055102,c=1.$